# How to save previously added items in hidden input tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML table with checkboxes, the table is generated on the basis of filter values selected in dropdowns
I am trying to fetch the values of checked checkboxes as ids of students then put them in an array "selected" then the elements in this array are added to the hidden input tag one by one. For e.g If I selected a filter called 5th class, the students of 5th class are listed in the table with the checkbox. Now if I checked some students their ids are stored hidden input tag successfully.

```js
var selected = [];
//On click check all records
$(document).on("click", "#completebatch,.commoncheckbox", function() {

selected = $('.commoncheckbox:checked').map((i, el) => {
  return $(el).attr('value')
}).get();

$("#allStudentIds").val(selected);

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th><input onclick="checkenabledisable()" id="completebatch" type="checkbox"></th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="commoncheckbox disabled-check" value="578" type="checkbox" disabled=""></td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input class="commoncheckbox" value="357" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="commoncheckbox" value="123" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="hidden" value="" id="allStudentIds">
```

Now lets suppose I have select some students from 6th class. The list of 6th class students will be generated successfully in the table. Now When I wiil check any checkbox, all the previously selected items get vanished (i.e in the above example the ids of 5th class students in hidden input tag gets vanished).

I want that this should not happen. I want to maintain the previously selected ids in hidden input tag.

Comment: Are you missing document ready wrapper in your example? The example is giving an error because of that.

Comment: yes this javascript function is wrapped around ready function

Comment: Then edit the question and fix the example.

Comment: Why have you removed the question @Amin ? I have an answer for you... try to  post it again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
...
var previousIds = $("#allStudentIds").val();
$("#allStudentIds").val(previousIds+selected);
...
```

If there is a possibility to duplicated `id` you can remove them before set value to `#allStudentIds` input